# .pem to .p12 certificate for APNS

Tags: java, ios, openssl, push-notification

I have a PEM file in format:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFrTCCBJWgAwIBAgIIT+eTOPXOV1MwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgZYxCzAJBgNV
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
friendlyName: Nat..
localKeyID: 58 EE 51 ...
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIFDjBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQIoYSd5mU27NYCAggA..
b+0W+xI4qbvXsRHXqvPshIwLGhVKtbgAx2cvlvmu2h49MB6DpxGklylJI+tiyLIT
mQ0=
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And I want to load it to push a notification by:

```
Push.payload(p, fileStream, "password", false, "devId")
```

I was trying to convert this file to .p12 but unfortunately all the time I get unknown or expired certificate when I try to use it. I got this file from a member of another team. How can I convert it properly?

Comment: You get that error when you try what?

Comment: When I do any connection to APNS. I'm getting expired_certificate or unknown_certificate error.

Comment: Well...how did you convert it?  And when does the certificate expire?

Comment: I have splitted the file to app.pem and key.pem and used openssl: openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.pem -in app.pem -out dev.p12

Comment: @jww No, this did not work.